# How to setup Princeton cos 126 development environment?

Tags: java

I followed all of the steps for setting up the development environment from the following website:
[enter link description here](https://lift.cs.princeton.edu/java/windows/)

However, when I compile/run code (from the terminal) I have to use a different syntax than what I see in the textbook.
Example:
My Code:
`

> javac -classpath ".\path\to\library.jar;" MyCode.java

> java -classpath ".\path\to\library.jar;" MyCode`

Textbook Code:
[image]

The issue arises when I have to write code with the StdLib lilbrary. I can get the code to run, but only with a long complicated --classpath option at the end. I don't know what I've installed wrong but, it's really bothering me that I can't figure this out. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you see the section of the page you linked titled: “Textbook Libraries (from the command line)”? It explains how to use wrapper scripts to set the classpath. It’s also possible to set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable to avoid needing to put it on the command line each time. However, there’s nothing wrong with the way you’ve done it.

Comment: @TimMoore I've read about creating an environment variable to avoid this issue, but that it can also create more problems in other programs. I think that my issue is the "wrapper script". I'm unable to compile with "javac-introcs my_file.java" or run with "java-introcs my_file". This is why I'm unsure what I've installed incorrectly.